# Difference between 'var a = b' and 'this.a = b'

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have been dealing and learning about Objects and OOP in JS in the past few days and I good a basic understanding how they work now.

One thing that bothers me, and I have problems with to understand, is where is the difference between this:

```
var bird = "Birdy: var bird"
```

and this

```
this.bird = "Birdy: this.bird"
```

Both of them will add a property(*bird*) to the object. In this case *this* points to the *object Window*. Where is the difference? Why are people using the *this.*bird method? What are the advantages of it(could someone show me an **example** where *this.bird* is superior to *var bird*)?

Let´s take this [tutorial](http://www.lessmilk.com/tutorial/2d-platformer-phaser) for example: why is he using *this* there? Isnt *this* redundant? Couldnt this entire thing be done removing the *this* and/or replacing it?

Comment: Because `this` isn't always the `window`. It can be pretty much any object, depending how a function is called.

Comment: Refer [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more clarification please.

Comment: @those who marked as duplicate: the duplicate tagging is completely wrong

Comment: Find your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43450264/2737783, as this question is marked duplicate.

Comment: Right @Jonasw, maybe someone is out of his mind.

Comment: @ManvendraSK Yo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope youre wrong. var adds a property to the current *functional context:*

```
obj={
  add:function(){
    var plane="test";
    this.bird="test2";
  }//plane gets deleted right here as it isnt used anymoreand it was never part of obj
};

obj.add();
obj.plane;//never existed
console.log(obj.bird);
```

Comment: Thanks for this really good example! So using the this keyword allows using the property(bird) to be used in other context(outside the function)?

Comment: @Faizy right! everything that uses var is deleted when the function returns.

Comment: @Faizy may have a look at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28Programmierung%29 in your preferred language...

Comment: One more question: if I use 'this' inside an function, where will it actually point to? Form example: 'function test() { this.test1 = "test2"} ? Which object is 'this' pointing/referring to now?

Comment: Ah, it will point to the Window Object, since function test() is assigend to the Object Window, right? One more question though: let´s take your woderful  example above. If I run it and take a look where the 'this' points to, it will show me only 'Object...'. Is there a way to get the exact name of the Object where it points to(in this cas it would be "obj")? @Jonas w

Comment: @Fauzy thispointsto.functionwiththis(); as an easy to remember rule. So yes youre right (window.test()). And no you cannot get its name...